# Can't Link to liborocos-kdl.so.1.1

Tags: ros, orocos, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't run robot_state_publisher, installed on Hydro from debians. I get the following error message.

```
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher: error while loading shared libraries: liborocos-kdl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Versions:

```
> dpkg -s ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher | grep 'Version'
Version: 1.9.10-0precise-20131228-0321-+0000
> dpkg -s ros-hydro-orocos-kdl | grep 'Version'
Version: 1.2.1-0precise-20131209-0906-+0000
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/116401/can%27t-link-to-liborocos-kdl.so.1.1/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2014-01-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-03-21**:
It appears 1.1 is for Groovy while 1.2 is for Hydro.  I'm currently getting the same problem.  Although both Groovy and Hydro are installed on this computer (shared lab) I know Hydro was sourced during my entire time doing this. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/KS6fCrztt_0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Clean remove and then reinstall. Bah.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-03-21**:
Is this how you solved it?